# Adding HTML within a PHP loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a wordpress theme which i'd like to add a line of static html to (an email address):
[Motors](https://themeforest.net/item/motors-automotive-cars-vehicle-boat-dealership-classifieds-wordpress-theme/13987211)

these social links are added in the customizer - as you can see - there's nowhere to add an email address.

[image]

the theme developers will not help, so i'm at a bit of a loss, but seem to recall something about adding html inside php, in a *specific* way.
this is **not** rendering on the front end.

```
<!-- Header top bar Socials -->
<?php if( !empty($socials) ): ?>
<div class="pull-right">
<div class="header-top-bar-socs">
<ul class="clearfix">
<?php foreach ( $socials as $key => $val ): ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($val) ?>" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@domain.com" style="text-transform:lowercase;">info@domain.com</a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

it's this line (line 13) i'm trying to add as there's no facility to add an email address:

`<li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@domain.com" style="text-transform:lowercase;">info@domain.com</a></li>`

can anyone point me in the right direction?
thanks heaps,
Jason

```
$top_bar = get_theme_mod('top_bar_enable', true);
$top_bar_login = get_theme_mod('top_bar_login', true);
$top_bar_wpml_switcher = get_theme_mod('top_bar_wpml_switcher', true);

if(!empty($top_bar) and $top_bar):
    
global $sitepress;
    
?>
    <div id="top-bar">
        <div class="container">

            <?php if(function_exists('icl_get_languages')):
                $langs = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', 'skip_missing=1&orderby=id&order=asc', null );
            endif; ?>
            <div class="clearfix top-bar-wrapper">
            <!--LANGS-->
            <?php if(!empty($top_bar_wpml_switcher) and $top_bar_wpml_switcher): ?>
                <?php if(!empty($langs)): ?>
                    <?php
                    if(count($langs) > 1 || is_author()){
                        $langs_exist = 'dropdown_toggle';
                    } else {
                        $langs_exist = 'no_other_langs';
                    }
                    
                    $current_lang = '';
                    $current_lang_flag = '';
                    if(!empty($langs[ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE])) {
                        $current_lang = $langs[ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE];
                        if(!empty($current_lang['country_flag_url'])) {
                            $current_lang_flag = $current_lang['country_flag_url'];
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="pull-left language-switcher-unit">
                        <div class="stm_current_language <?php echo esc_attr($langs_exist); ?>" <?php if(count($langs) > 1 || is_author()){ ?> id="lang_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" <?php } ?>>
                            <?php if(stm_is_rental() and !empty($current_lang_flag)): ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($current_lang_flag); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e('Language flag', 'motors') ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo esc_attr(ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME); ?><?php if(count($langs) > 1 || is_author()){ ?><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i><?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if(count($langs) > 1 && !is_author()): ?>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu lang_dropdown_menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="lang_dropdown">
                                <?php foreach($langs as $lang): ?>
                                    <?php if(!$lang['active']): ?>
                                        <li role="presentation">
                                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo esc_url($lang['url']); ?>">
                                                <?php if(stm_is_rental() and !empty($lang['country_flag_url'])): ?>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($lang['country_flag_url']); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e('Language flag', 'motors') ?>" />
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php echo esc_attr($lang['native_name']); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php elseif(is_author()):
                            $user = get_user_by("ID", get_current_user_id());
                            
                            ?>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu lang_dropdown_menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="lang_dropdown">
                                <?php foreach(icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0') as $val) :?>
                                    <?php
                                    $request_uri = str_replace("/" . wpml_get_current_language() . "/", "/", apply_filters('stm_get_global_server_val', "REQUEST_URI"));
                                    if(!$val['active']):
                                        $mainUrl =  $sitepress->language_url($val["code"]);
                                        
                                        $url_append = "";
                                        if(is_multisite()) {
                                            $ms_slug = get_blog_details()->path;
                                            $request_uri = str_replace($ms_slug, "", $request_uri);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <li role="presentation">
                                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo esc_url($mainUrl . $request_uri); ?>">
                                                <?php if(stm_is_rental() and !empty($val['country_flag_url'])): ?>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($val['country_flag_url']); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e('Language flag', 'motors') ?>" />
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php echo esc_attr($val['native_name']); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php stm_getCurrencySelectorHtml(); ?>
                <!-- Header Top bar Login -->
                <?php if(!empty($top_bar_login) and $top_bar_login): ?>
                    <?php
                    if(!is_listing()): ?>
                        <?php if ( class_exists("WooCommerce") ): ?>
                            <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                                <div class="header-login-url">
                                    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
                                        <?php if(!stm_is_rental()): ?>
                                        <a class="logout-link" href="<?php echo esc_url(wp_logout_url(home_url())); ?>" title="<?php _e('Log out', 'motors'); ?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-icon-stm_icon_user"></i>
                                            <?php _e('Log out', 'motors'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stm-rent-lOffer-account-unit-main">
                                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') )); ?>" class="stm-rent-lOffer-account-main">
                                                    <?php
                                                    if(is_user_logged_in()): $user_fields = stm_get_user_custom_fields('');
                                                        if(!empty($user_fields['image'])):
                                                            ?>
                                                            <div class="stm-dropdown-user-small-avatar">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($user_fields['image']); ?>" class="im-responsive"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <i class="stm-service-icon-user"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) )); ?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="vt-top"><?php _e('Login', 'motors'); ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) )); ?>"><?php _e('Register', 'motors'); ?></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php
                            $login_page = get_theme_mod( 'login_page', 1718);
                            $login_page = stm_motors_wpml_is_page($login_page);
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( !empty($login_page) ): ?>
                            <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                                <div class="header-login-url">
                                    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
                                        <a class="logout-link" href="<?php echo esc_url(wp_logout_url(home_url())); ?>" title="<?php _e('Log out', 'motors'); ?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-icon-stm_icon_user"></i>
                                            <?php _e('Log out', 'motors'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $login_page )); ?>">
                                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="vt-top"><?php _e('Login', 'motors'); ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <span class="vertical-divider"></span>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $login_page )); ?>"><?php _e('Register', 'motors'); ?></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $socials = stm_get_header_socials('top_bar_socials_enable'); ?>
                <!-- Header top bar Socials -->
                <?php if( !empty($socials) ): ?>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="header-top-bar-socs">
                            <ul class="clearfix">
                                <?php foreach ( $socials as $key => $val ): ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($val) ?>" target="_blank">
                                            <i class="fa fa-<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:info@domain.com" style="text-transform:lowercase;">info@domain.com</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                $top_bar_address = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_address', '1010 Moon ave, New York, NY US' );
                $top_bar_address_mobile = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_address_mobile', true );

                $top_bar_working_hours = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_working_hours', 'Mon - Sat 8.00 - 18.00' );
                $top_bar_working_hours_mobile = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_working_hours_mobile', true );

                $top_bar_phone = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_phone', '+1 212-226-3126' );
                $top_bar_phone_mobile = get_theme_mod( 'top_bar_phone_mobile', true );

                $top_bar_menu = get_theme_mod('top_bar_menu', false);

                if( $top_bar_menu ): ?>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <div class="top_bar_menu">
                                <?php get_template_part('partials/top-bar', 'menu'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php endif;
                
                if( $top_bar_address || $top_bar_working_hours || $top_bar_phone ): ?>
                    <div class="pull-right xs-pull-left">
                        <ul class="top-bar-info clearfix">
                            <?php if( $top_bar_working_hours ){ ?>
                                <li <?php if(!$top_bar_working_hours_mobile){ ?>class="hidden-info"<?php } ?>><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php stm_dynamic_string_translation_e('Top Bar Working Hours Label',  $top_bar_working_hours); ?></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $top_bar_address ){ ?>
                                <?php $header_address_url = get_theme_mod('header_address_url'); ?>
                                <li <?php if(!$top_bar_address_mobile){ ?>class="hidden-info"<?php } ?>>
                                    <span id="top-bar-address" class="fancy-iframe" data-iframe="true" data-src="<?php echo esc_attr($header_address_url); ?>">
                                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php stm_dynamic_string_translation_e('Top Bar Address', $top_bar_address ); ?>
                                    </span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $top_bar_phone ){ ?>
                                <li <?php if(!$top_bar_phone_mobile){ ?>class="hidden-info"<?php } ?>><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <a href="tel:<?php echo esc_attr($top_bar_phone); ?>"><?php stm_dynamic_string_translation_e('Top Bar Phone', $top_bar_phone ); ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No picture with code, copy the code directly as Code Sample here.

Comment: apologies - sorted

Comment: Try to be a bit more clear on what you're trying to achieve, what do you mean by "this is not rendering on the front end"? Just be a bit more clear i'm sure we can help

Comment: you cleared cache (e.g. CTRL + F5 (or Cmd + R on Mac) ) to update for change(s) in your browser?

Comment: ok, i have added that code above to the appropriate template file & uploaded to the server, however that line of html (the email address) is not appearing when browsing the site. it's not even in the source code of the page when viewed. if there are no special requirements when adding a line oh html inside a foreach loop & having it render, then i guess the template file is incorrect? they did specifically tell me which file to edit though.

Comment: yes, cache is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

first of all its important to note that your code is looking for '$socials' - I assume this is a setting in your theme options that allows you to add social media links. Without at least one of these set, nothing will show.

Then, inside the 'foreach' loop, you are going to show the same email address every time one of these social links is displayed which is also not correct. Try moving your code to after the 'endforeach'.

Lastly, editing theme files is bad practice. Create a child theme and just replace the files required to do this part. When the theme is updated, you wont lose your changes.

Comment: thanks Innate, i am using a child theme - not modifying the original files, & there are other social links entered in the customiser - there's just no ability to add an email address here, & the client wants it.
I'll try moving it as you suggested.

Comment: groovy. have you added a social link to the theme options?

Comment: Was pretty much gonna say the same as @Innate ... Could you please paste the whole file, and parent template?

Comment: ok, i've moved it below the endforeach statement, that makes perfect sense - so thanks for the heads up. still nothing showing on the front end though, so i'm starting to wonder if the devs gave me the incorrect file to edit.

Comment: i've added the complete code of that file - hope that helps

Comment: If your website is online, could you also paste the url

Comment: Better still, tell us the name of the theme. That part of the code is only going to show if you have allowed something in you theme options. Are any social media links showing on the frong end? Can you add these in the backend anywhere?

Comment: sure thing, i really appreciate your help by the way...

Comment: the parent theme file (top-bar.php) is in: /wp-content/themes/motors/partials/ - i've placed the modified file in: /wp-content/themes/motors-child/partials/

Comment: ok as this is not a main theme file, you will need to include the main file too; i.e. header.php and all the files it includes in your child theme or they will just be ignored.

Comment: ahhhh... i had no idea, i'll give that a shot - thank you

Comment: Hey Jason, did you get this sorted out?